# Keep UIButtons centered using autolayout in storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have two buttons contained within a view (to be precise, a `UITableView` footer):

[image]

I would like to keep the buttons centered (with the gap in-between) regardless of the width of the superview (which will increase, for example, if the device is rotated to portrait orientation).

Is there a way to define these autolayout constraints purely in the storyboard, or will I need to use `NSLayoutConstraints` in code?

Comment: Why has this question been marked down? I think that it's a valid question to ask...

Comment: it's helpful. Suggest me the best autolayout tricks to my mail (nazirjaleel@gmail.com) thanks....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding a constraint for each button to align the leading/trailing to the center of the container view, plus some separation between them.

How to do it:

- For the left side button, add a constraint between the button and superview to center it horizontally.
- Edit the constraint and change the "Second Item" attribute to be button1.trailing, and set a constant of 10 (or whatever distance you want between the right border of the button and the center of the screen).

[image: alignmentConstraint1]

- For the right side button, add a constraint between the button and superview to center it horizontally.
- Edit the constraint and change the "Second Item" attribute to be button2.leading and set a constant of -10 (or whatever distance you want between the left border of the button and the center of the screen).

[image]

Comment: The art of auto layout